# Uniqueness of solution to PDE with a local boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Does the following PDE with local boundary condition have a unique solution:

\begin{cases} 
      \hfill \Delta u=0  \hfill & \Omega \\
      \hfill \frac{\partial u}{\partial n_+}- \frac{\partial u}{\partial n_-}=u\hfill & \partial\Omega, \\
  \end{cases}
where $\frac{\partial }{\partial n_+}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial n_-}$ are the exterior and interior normal derivatives.

Comment: If $u$ is defined on $\bar\Omega$, how do you define the exterior normal derivative?

Comment: I agree.let say we know a priori that $u$ is defined in a larger domain containing $\Omega$.

Comment: In that case $n_+=-n_-$, the normal derivatives have oposite signs and the boundary condition becomes a Robin boundary condition.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre the reason behind my question is whether single layer potentials are equivalent to solutions to this equation (supposedly should be obvious but  I don't see why).

Comment: If $u$ is a solution, then $t u$ will be also a solution for any $t \neq 0$.